# Django REST framework serializers: multiple fields mapping to one property

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a model that has a `flags` property, which is a bitmask of multiple values. I want to expose it as an API using `django-rest-framework`, where the different flags are different boolean properties. Say, if the flags are `FLAG_NEW=1`, `FLAG_DELETED=2`, I want to expose `isNew` and `isDeleted` fields. For read-only models, this is easy - just use a `SerializerModelField` and get whether the flag is set. However, that doesn't work when I want to deserialize (this is a read-only field). I could use a custom field, but then what should I put in the `source=` parameter? They will overwrite each other if I put `source=flags` and if I don't, then how do I get the initial value?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    FLAG_NEW = 1
    FLAG_DELETED = 2

    flags = models.IntegerField()

....

class MyModelSerializer(models.Model):
    isDeleted = ???
    isNew = ???
```

Comment: why don't you add `BooleanField` instead of model atribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    FLAG_NEW = 1
    FLAG_DELETED = 2

    flags = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def isNew(self):
        return self.flags | self.FLAG_NEW

    @isNew.setter
    def isNew(self, value):
        if value:
            self.flags |= self.FLAG_NEW
        else:
            self.flags &= ~self.FLAG_NEW

    @property
    def isDeleted(self):
        return self.flags | self.FLAG_DELETED

    @isDeleted.setter
    def isDeleted(self, value):
        if value:
            self.flags |= self.FLAG_DELETED
        else:
            self.flags &= ~self.FLAG_DELETED
```

....

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'isNew', 'isDeleted', ...)
```